# Getting a reference of ActionBar's action icon

Tags: android

I want to animate a `ic_action_refresh` in the `ActionBar`. I'm using `AppCompat`, and so far I have done this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    if(item != null)
        refreshView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

The results are: `item` is ok, but `refreshView` is `null`.

Any idea of what can I do, or what am I missing?

**Edit**

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/action_refresh"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an animation (I'll assume a spinning ProgressBar) in a menu item use the following:

```
item.setActionView(new ProgressBar(YOUR APP CONTEXT));
```

and when you want to get rid of the progress bar simply do `item.setActionView(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ..

```
item.getActionView() // to get the current action view set for the item
```

but make sure you have already set action view for this item using..

```
item.setActionView(view)
```